# Как сделать рамку вокруг Label в WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Абсолютно без понятия, как это сделать.

Comment: [BorderStyle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.borderstyle?view=net-5.0)

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Jack_oS, вопрос и так хороший.

Answer (score 1):

[Собственно говоря код из доков.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.borderstyle?view=net-5.0)

```
public void CreateMyLabel()
{
   // Create an instance of a Label.
   Label label1 = new Label();

   // Set the border to a three-dimensional border.
   label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
   // Set the ImageList to use for displaying an image.
   label1.ImageList = imageList1;
   // Use the second image in imageList1.
   label1.ImageIndex = 1;
   // Align the image to the top left corner.
   label1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;

   // Specify that the text can display mnemonic characters.
   label1.UseMnemonic = true;
   // Set the text of the control and specify a mnemonic character.
   label1.Text = "First &Name:";
   
   /* Set the size of the control based on the PreferredHeight and PreferredWidth values. */
   label1.Size = new Size (label1.PreferredWidth, label1.PreferredHeight);

   //...Code to add the control to the form...
}
```

Comment: Вроде 3D не просили. Лейблам чаще плоская нужна.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я в винформах не разбираюсь. Написал этот ответ чисто загуглив наверно XD